# Como criar pixeis na tela em java

Tags: java, android

Estou construindo um aplicativo de desenho (Para um treino de progamação) e tive a seguinte dúvida, **Como criar pixeis pragamaticamente java na tela?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Bitmap , para criar faça assim:

```
Bitmap exemplo = Bitmap.createBitmap(500, 1000, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
//500 é a largura e 1000 a altura
```

Depois defina-o como mutável:

```
exemplo = exemplo.copy(exemplo.getConfig(), true);
```

E para desenhar o pixel utilize:

```
exemplo.setPixel(100, 200, Color.RED);
//Pintara o pixel da coordenada x:100 e y:200 com a cor vermelha
```

Comment: Obrigado, consegui fazer o que eu queria :)